# NSIS: How to use a paramter to build different installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to build my script differently depend how I set the paramter.

I call my script like here:

`makensis test.nsi -DFLAG=10` or `makensis test.nsi -DFLAG=8`.

I tried to use it as a paramter like here

```
${If} ${FLAG} == 10
   ...
${IfElse} ${FLAG} == 8
   ....
${Else}
    !error "Set the Flag."
${IfEnd}
```

But I still get only there error message.

I tried also to use `GetParamters` from the documentation 4.12.

```
include FileFunc.nsh
!insertmacro GetParameters
!insertmacro GetOptions

${GetParameters} $R0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $R0 -DFLAG= $0
!echo $R0
```

But it only returns `$R0` and not the value. What are the mistake or are there a besser strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you must execute it as `makensis -DFLAG=8 test.nsi` because the parameters are parsed in same order as you pass them in. From the documentation:

> Parameters are processed in order. `makensis /Ddef script.nsi` is not the same as `makensis script.nsi /Ddef`.

Secondly, you cannot mix `${If}` with `!error` because the former is a run-time instruction and the latter is a compile-time instruction.

Use `!if ${FLAG} = 8` or `!ifdef FLAG`.

`GetParameters` returns the parameters passed to the installer on the end-users system, not the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. Your are the best!